# JIRA: How to get resolved vs closed? using JQL?

Tags: jira

Is there a way in JIRA via the filters or using JQL Query to get resolved vs closed over a time frame?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use dashboard gadget for this. have tested "Issue Statistics" gadget and works fine. you can create a filter that you need with a time frame then configure the gadget with the status and created filter.image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dataplane Reporting Services handles this quite well.